# Hcreate thread inside a android map

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps

Im trying to implement an Android app, 
In the main activity it's displaying a google map , and Im trying to implement a Video view also on the same layout .
So With in the main map activity (while map is displaying) im trying to implement a thread which will invoke the videoview activity(to do recording) below the map view at the same time.

Is this possible ?
because Im getting lot of errors.
Please can anyone help me..?
Thanks

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements Runnable{

```
private MapView mapView;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
private Button playerbtn;//button to start player
private Button recorderbtn;//button for recorder
private VideoView mVideoView;
private Uri mVideoUri;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    playerbtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.playback);
    recorderbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recording);

    // main.xml contains a MapView
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    // extract MapView from layout
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // create an overlay that shows our current location
    myLocationOverlay = new FixedMyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);

    // add this overlay to the MapView and refresh it
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

    // call convenience method that zooms map on our location
    zoomToMyLocation();



}

//--videoview

public void recordingListner(View view) {

    Thread toRun = new Thread()
       {
              public void run()
              {

                 final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoRecorder.class);
                handleCameraVideo(intent);
                startActivity(intent);    

              }
       };
       toRun.start();
```

}

```
private void handleCameraVideo(Intent intent) {
    mVideoUri = intent.getData();
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ralgha for reply,when I run the application, by default the map appers , but when I press the button to start the VideoView which located below the MapView , it closes the application by giving an exception syaing  IOException from android runtime. which i dont understand why? because video acitivity runs on a different thread as well.Please help me..?Thanks

Comment: Post the complete log output please.

Comment: 10-28 00:57:10.936: W/dalvikvm(451): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-28 00:57:10.946: E/AndroidRuntime(451): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
10-28 00:57:10.946: E/AndroidRuntime(451): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 00:57:10.946: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.tdk.crashcam.MainActivity.handleCameraVideo(MainActivity.java:59)
10-28 00:57:10.946: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.tdk.crashcam.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:57)
10-28 00:57:10.946: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.tdk.crashcam.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:49)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.  You have to call setContentView before you call findViewById.